# Is there some way to change the backround of keyboard and color of keys?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to change the color of keys and background of keyboard. Is there some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer: no.

Any virtual keyboards are just some part of an input method "application". That is, if you want to change the color of a specific virtual keyboard, you need to change the drawables or the styles which are used by the keyboard.

The only way to achieve your need is "write one IME by yourself."

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of any key by the entry in xml file.

Just to write

```
android:keyIcon="@drawable/ "
```

instead of

```
android:keyLabel="".
```

Comment: And which .xml file should I put this? There are several .xml files, such as manifest, layout, helpers and so on...